# Using IsPrime method in Java

Tags: java

This is my code to use IsPrime method to determine total number of primes between 0 and 1000 and print the total number of primes at last. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int z=0; 
    // z is the variable that holds total number of primes
    //n is divisor
    //i is dividend

    if (isPrime(i)) {
        z++;
    }
    System.out.print(z+"\n");
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n){
             { 
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        for(n=0; n<i; n++)
            if(i%n==0) 
                return false;
            else 
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First problem is (lack of) consistent formatting.. I stop reading when encountering such.

Comment: I edited it. Just waiting for it to get approved.

Comment: Try to organize and format  better  the code

Comment: Please describe the problem that you are having with this code. It's not a guessing game

Comment: Logic Written in isPrime(int n) is wrong.

Comment: just put this code in any IDE and remove the compilation error.

Comment: Hej the problem is your logic in the code, you know that primes are only divisible by 1 and themselves. and the primes starts from 2. Second you should always use long in the paramiter, thired if the n < 2 you should return false, forth problem is your for loop. write instead for(long  i= 2; i * i <=  n; i++) if(n%i== 0) it is not prime, return false, else return true,

Answer (score 3):

Formatting it might help you discover the error.

I see a few things that's wrong with your code:

1. From what I can see, you have an extra open curly bracket in your `isPrime` method.
2. `i` isn't declared in your main method.
3. You need to wrap your `if(isPrime(i))` statement inside a for loop that goes from 0 to 1000. Like the following:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
       if (isPrime(i))
           z++;
   }
   ```

   That way, it will be actually checking all the prime numbers from 0 to 1000
4. For good coding practices, I would name your `z` variable to be something like `counter` so that it's clear what that variable is supposed to be doing. `i` in for-loop is okay since that's a common way to index through the loop.
5. You can also use several tactics to optimize your code. You can use `Math.sqrt()` function, as well as start your for loop from 3 and go up by increment of 2 (since any even number will be dividable by 2) and initialize your counter from 1 since 2 will already be a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    int factors = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(n % i == 0) // ensure that you mod n not i
        factors++;
     }
    // if factors count is equals to 2 then it is prime number else it's not prime number
    if(factors == 2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Check this modified code once for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a few things turned around.

Why not loop from 1 to 1000 in your primary function and then use the isPrime function to determine if each number is prime.

In the isPrime function, you count from 2 to 1/2 the value of the number and do the divisions to determine if it is prime.  Return False if it is divisible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int z=0; 
  for (i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
       if (isPrime(i))
       {
           z++;
       }
    }
    System.out.print(z+"\n");
}
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
        for(i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
        {
           if(n%i==0) return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare i for isPrime to compile.  And it claims that 4 is a prime.

Comment: You should iterate from `2` to `sqrt(n)+1` in `isPrime()` internal loop.

Comment: You're right .. should have had i<=n/2.  Didn't declar i .. was in a hurry.

Comment: mbaitoff ... yep, sqrt would be faster wouldn't it.

Comment: You should iterate from 3 by odds to sqrt(n) -- treat anything less than 3 as a special case.

Comment: Wow, we're all the same aren't we ... always looking for the most efficient way to get something done.  I'm not a big fan of special-case coding, but you're right, it could be done that way.

Answer (score -1):

This will count the number of primes based on this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/check-a-number-is-prime-number-or-not-in-c-sharp1) and your original answer...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int isPrimeCount = 0;

    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        if(Check_Prime(i))
        {
          isPrimeCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(isPrimeCount);
    }
}

private static boolean Check_Prime(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= number - 1; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    if (i == number)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: very nice copy pasta XD

Comment: The question is "Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code.". It's not "Give me some completely unrelated piece of code that does the same thing but doesn't teach me anything"

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the variable "i" before you pass it to the isPrime() method in main(). It seems as though whoever wrote the code did not fully understand what a prime number was. According to wikipedia "A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. " With this in mind you need to make sure that the value you pass to the isPrime() method is greater than 1. After look at your code I made some changes. I made the isPrime() method return false if the input value is <=1. Also, I made the isPrime() method return true if the input value is 2. I made other changes in the code that would make the for statement operate n-1 times because that is all that is needed to find out if the number is prime because all numbers are divisible by themselves. Also the for statement starts at the value 2. Your if-then-else return statements within the for loop is illogical because it will return a value without going through the entire loop. You did not need the inner for loop.
Here's [a link on prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Here is the new code:

```
public class AreaComparison {

    /**
     * Starts the program.
     *
     * @param command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = 0;
        int i = 2;
    // z is the variable that holds total number of primes
        //n is divisor
        //i is dividend

        if (isPrime(i)) {
            z++;
        }
        System.out.print(z + "\n");
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if(n == 2){
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {

            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This has a small mistake, inside the loop it should be return false, and the last return should be true.